# integrating sqlalchemy in webapp2

Tags: sqlalchemy, webapp2

I'm developing an app using webapp2 outside google appengine, I want to integrate sqlalchemy and found an example on http://webpy.org/cookbook/sqlalchemy so I used the models.py from the example and in my main.py I defined my BaseHandler like this:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        """ 
        returns ORM handle to the database
        Usage: admin = self.db.query(User).filter_by(name='admin').first()
        """
        return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

My question is that, is this the recommended way to do this? Is their other way?

Comment: I think it looks fine. I have seen it done slightly differently where this is abstracted out and used by classes strictly for data access and your handler executes methods from these data access classes which may be more clear. My thinking is handlers are really for constructing views and dont need to directly access the database.